# UICollectionvView Cell placement

Tags: storyboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, size-classes

I have an UICollectionvView with 13 cells designed with Storyboard and SizeClasses.

How can I tell my CollectionView that it should show only complete Cells?
At the moment cells on the rightside Edge are cut of.

The UICollectionView should work on Ipad an Iphone for landscape and portrait.
On the iPad max 13cells per Page should be visible and on the iPhone max 3Cells per Page should be visible.

[image]